# Which one is the best Java datepicker..?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, datepicker

I need a well done gui swing java datechooser.. I only find some ugly datepickers from 199x

does somebody know a nice gui datepicker?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[SwingLabs](http://java.net/projects/swinglabs) has [SwingX](http://swingx.java.net/) project which provides suite of components including [**JXDatePicker**](http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t45447.html) ([API](http://download.java.net/javadesktop/swinglabs/releases/0.8/docs/api/org/jdesktop/swingx/JXDatePicker.html)) works with [Date](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) class, which **supports dates starting from January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT**.

[Try demo](http://swinglabs-demos.java.net/demos/swingxset6/swingxset.jnlp), as an option. Not 199x and not ugly. Widely supported and used.

Comment: Too bad most links are broken. :-/

Comment: Yeah, seems like java.net is dead T_T

Answer (score 6):

Maybe you want to try [JCalendar](http://www.toedter.com/en/jcalendar/).

Comment: do you know how to implement it? or a tutorial link?

Comment: Examples are included in the [distribution](http://www.toedter.com/en/jcalendar/).

Comment: @fuzi- Download and open the latest version, it includes a demo class, you can take a look at it http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/com/luuuis/jcalendar-tz/1.3.3-3/jcalendar-tz-1.3.3-3-sources.jar!/com/toedter/calendar/demo/JCalendarDemo.java?format=ok

Answer (score 6):

I have used several date choosers, and I would recommend **[LGoodDatePicker](https://github.com/LGoodDatePicker/LGoodDatePicker)**.
Other common libraries are: [JXDatePicker](http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t45447.html), [Microba DatePicker](https://github.com/tdbear/microba), [JDatePicker](https://github.com/JDatePicker/JDatePicker), and [JCalendar](http://toedter.com/jcalendar/).

Fair disclosure: I'm the primary LGoodDatePicker developer.

LGoodDatePicker general features list:
(Copied from the project page)

- The components are the DatePicker, TimePicker, DateTimePicker, and CalendarPanel.
- Automatic localization (internationalization), to 22 languages.
  (Arabic, Chinese, Czech, Danish, Dutch, English, French, German, Greek, Hindi, Italian, Indonesian, Japanese, Korean, Polish, Portuguese, Romanian, Russian, Spanish, Swedish, Turkish, Vietnamese.)
- Natively uses the standard Java 8 time package (aka java.time.LocalDate or "JSR-310").
- Also supports other data types, such as "java.util.Date".
- Customizable visual elements.  (Including calendar size, fonts, colors, and the popup border.)
- The TimePicker GUI provides a time selection list and (optional) spinner buttons.
- Automatic date/time validation on all components.
- Optional highlight policies and veto policies.
- Can allow or disallow empty values. (Null dates or times.)
- Simple usage. Creating a picker requires only one line of code.
- Includes the [Demo Program](https://github.com/LGoodDatePicker/LGoodDatePicker/releases), and code examples.
- Complete Javadoc documentation.
- Active developer support.
- Open source MIT license.

I pasted screenshots of  the components (and the demo program) below.

The library can be installed into your Java project from the project [release page](https://github.com/LGoodDatePicker/LGoodDatePicker/releases).

The project home page is on Github at:
https://github.com/LGoodDatePicker/LGoodDatePicker .

[image: DateTimePicker screenshot]

[image: DateTimePicker examples]

[image: Demo screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

Check JDatePicker its also good. In JXDatePicker there is no year changing option.

Check example of JDatePicker 
http://www.codejava.net/java-se/swing/how-to-use-jdatepicker-to-display-calendar-component