# What's the Best way to accept a 'date of birth' value and store it in a database

Tags: java, database, date, netbeans

I created a Swing GUI form in Netbeans to accept Student Details. The details include studentId, Surname, Middle Name, first Name, Date of birth and others. I tried accepting date of birth values with 3 combo boxes. I don't know how to store this combo box values in a database. Note: I created a table and set a column 'dOB' with 'date' data type. If the comboBox can't be used? Any other suggestions?

Comment: Most databases I know of have a native "date" type so just store it as one in the database.

Comment: @CashCow my main problem is not the data type, rather how to store the selected values in the combo boxs in a database. You get?

Comment: How about Datapicker ?

[You may check this answer][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9368450/which-one-is-the-best-java-datepicker

Comment: You use whatever widget and get the date from it in a native Date format. Then store it in the database.

Comment: @TomiO'maiye Please search StackOverflow before posting. Even now you can notice a bunch of related questions on the lower right if viewing this in a web browser.

Answer (score 2):

'Date' data type is in format of 'YYYY-MM-DD'. So you can get string value of each combo box and then combine it into a string in format of birthDate = Year + "-" + Month +  "-" + Day; Then store birthDate in DB