# How can I make a calendar using JComboBox?

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox, localdate

I want to make it adaptive, like if Feb got 29 days in 2000 but it will change into 28 when 2001.

I want to do it while using `JComboBox`

How can I make action calendar using a combo box?

```
    JComboBox jcb,jcb1,jcb2;    
    db(){
    JFrame jf = new JFrame("register");
    jf.setLayout=(new FlowLayout());
    DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy");
    String aa1="0"+1+"-"+"0"+2+"-"+2000;
    date = LocalDate.parse(aa1,dtf);
    Integer day[] = new Integer[date.lengthOfMonth()];
    for(int i=0;i<date.lengthOfMonth();i++) {
        day[i]=i+1;
    }
    jcb = new JComboBox<>(day);
    Integer month[] = new Integer[12];
    for(int i=0;i<12;i++) {
        month[i]=i+1;
    }
    jcb1 = new JComboBox<>(month);

    Integer year[] = new Integer[80];
    for(int i=0;i<80;i++) {
        year[i]=i+1940;
    }
    jcb2 = new JComboBox<>(year);
    jf.add(jcb);
    jf.add(jcb1);
    jf.add(jcb2);
    jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    jf.setBounds(300,300,300,300);
    jf.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: What's the difference between an 'action calendar' & an 'inaction calendar'? What does 'action' mean to you? BTW - I feel you are jumping the gun here to want a combo box. It is likely not the best component for the job.

Comment: i mean i want to change my date into 1-29 when my month GetseletedItem Feb and year GetselectedItem 2000
and if i select my year into 2001 it will only 1-28 in Feb...
sorry for wrong usage..

Comment: *"sorry for wrong usage."* All we (OK I - shouldn't presume for others) needed was an explanation - which you gave. Thanks for that. BTW - I edited the question a bit to make best chance everyone can understand it.

Comment: yes.. someone just helped me becoz of ur editing 
that helped a lot 
thank you too..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Andrew Thompson mentioned in comments, JComboBoxes for date selection is not a good idea. Take a look at [Which one is the best Java datepicker.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9368450/which-one-is-the-best-java-datepicker)

However, if you still insist of using comboboxes, in order to achieve what you want, you will have to add an `ActionListener` to month/year combobox in order to re-fix the model (items) of days combobox.

Take a look at this example:

```
public class Test extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    private JComboBox<Integer> yearBox;
    private JComboBox<Integer> monthBox;
    private JComboBox<Integer> dayBox;

    public Test() {
        super("test");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        yearBox = new JComboBox<>();
        for (int i = 1940; i <= LocalDateTime.now().getYear(); i++) {
            yearBox.addItem(i);
        }
        yearBox.addActionListener(this);

        monthBox = new JComboBox<>();
        for (int i = 1; i <= 12; i++) {
            monthBox.addItem(i);
        }
        monthBox.addActionListener(this);

        dayBox = new JComboBox<>();

        add(new JLabel("year:"));
        add(yearBox);
        add(new JLabel("month:"));
        add(monthBox);
        add(new JLabel("day:"));
        add(dayBox);

        //Start with current year selected
        yearBox.setSelectedIndex(yearBox.getItemCount() - 1);

        setSize(400, 400);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        int year = (int) yearBox.getSelectedItem();
        int month = (int) monthBox.getSelectedItem();
        int daysInThisMonth = LocalDate.of(year, month, 1).lengthOfMonth();
        int previousSelection = dayBox.getSelectedItem() != null ? (int) dayBox.getSelectedItem() : 1;
        dayBox.removeAllItems();
        for (int i = 1; i <= daysInThisMonth; i++) {
            dayBox.addItem(i);
        }
        if (previousSelection >= dayBox.getItemCount())
            //select last index of month
            dayBox.setSelectedIndex(dayBox.getItemCount() - 1);
        else
            dayBox.setSelectedItem(previousSelection);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> new Test().setVisible(true));
    }

}
```

Comment: *"a bunch of JComboBoxes"* .. oh. You mean for year, month, day? That seems intuitively obvious once you mentioned there might be more than one combo! I need more coffee.

Comment: @dead_inside As I see you are a new user, take a look at [what should I do when someone answers my question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: @AndrewThompson You are right, but I had never think about it like this. Fixed :)